Set WebSphere server profile name via Ant
I try to automate an old product build. It's based on IBM RAD 9.7 and WebSphere 9.
I created a build.xml Ant file containing this:
[...]
    <target name="importAndBuildEverything" depends="init" >
        <disableIndexer name="jsp" />  
        <disableIndexer name="links" /> 
        
        <createWSRuntime targetId="was.v9.base" typeId="com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.v90" javaVersion="8.0" failOnError="false" />
        <projectImport ... />
        <createWSServer targetId="was90server" typeId="com.ibm.ws.ast.st.v9.server.base" runtimeId="was.v9.base">
        </createWSServer>
        <startWSServer serverId="was90server" />
[...]

But it fails on <startWSServer> task:
[...]
[startWSServer] Synchrones Starten der Serverinstanz 'WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0 @ localhost'. (Beginn)
[createWSServer] ... Hintergrundtask: createWSServer (Fertig)
[createWSServer] ... Hintergrundtask: createWSServer (Fertig)
[startWSServer] ... Hintergrundtask: WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0 @ localhost wird gestartet: Startstellvertreter wird vorbereitet... (Beginn)
[startWSServer] ... Hintergrundtaskstatus: Überprüfung vor Startvorgang wird ausgeführt...
[startWSServer] ... Hintergrundtaskstatus: Liste der vorausgesetzten Projekte wird gebuildet
[startWSServer] ... Hintergrundtaskstatus: Abschließende Startprüfung wird ausgeführt...
[startWSServer] ... Hintergrundtaskstatus: Quellenlocator wird initialisiert...
[startWSServer] ... Hintergrundtaskstatus: Erweiterung wird gestartet...
[startWSServer] ... Hintergrundtask: WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0 @ localhost wird gestartet: Startstellvertreter wird vorbereitet... (Fertig)
[startWSServer] Profilname  ist ungültig.  Geben Sie einen Profilnamen an, der auf dem Server vorhanden ist.
[startWSServer] Synchrones Starten der Serverinstanz 'WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0 @ localhost'. (Fertig)

BUILD FAILED
XXX\build.xml:95: Profilname  ist ungültig.  Geben Sie einen Profilnamen an, der auf dem Server vorhanden ist.

The error message in english is:
Profile name  is invalid.  Specify a profile name that exists on the server.
I cannot find any documentation about these Ant tasks. How to set a non-empty profile name so it doesn't fail anymore?

I solved this by opening RAD IDE, going to the Servers tab and deleting the servers. Then Ant created a new server which worked.
Also I've found the docs about these Ant tasks: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/radfws/9.7?topic=applications-ant-tasks-workbench-operations
